# Selenium webdriver error..It is unable to send keys with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver. I have searched many times and tried every answer in order to successfully testing a case. I am new to test automation.

**Problem:** There is an error when I use `.sendKeys()` and also click on some web element. I am really upset about this. I want to go forward with testing. Please help me solve this.

And also it displays an error stating `InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function`. Previously I have ran this codes successfully.

**My setup is a follows:**

- Firefox 53.0
- Eclipse Juno 32bit
- Selenium Wevdriver 3.3.1
- GeckoDriver 16.0
- logger `apache-log4j-1.2.17`

**This is the error:**

> 1495778288530 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:23817
>   1495778289152 mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path
>   C:\Users\EXTROG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.pTb73U1lR7sv
>   1495778289154 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program
>   Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args []
>   1495778289159 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on
>   localhost:50245 1495778293537 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50245
>   May 26, 2017 11:28:13 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: W3C **JavaScript error: , line 0:
>   uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function**  INFO
>   [main] (SearchBarTest.java:20)- search bar is there Error : Expected
>   [object Undefined] undefined to be a string Build info: version:
>   'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
>   System info: host: 'EXTROGENE-PC', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_121' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities
>   [{moz:profile=C:\Users\EXTROG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.pTb73U1lR7sv,
>   rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000},
>   pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0,
>   moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false,
>   browserVersion=53.0.3, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=1896,
>   browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID:
>   0d78f916-fa2e-4325-8baf-08b8e444d250

**This is my code:**

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='serchkey']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='serchkey']")).sendKeys(new String("toy"));
```

Comment: Is something wrong with `sendKeys("toy"));` instead of `.sendKeys(new String("toy"));` ?

Comment: @isharaThilakarathne Can you consider putting here the full error stacktrace along with the exception?

Comment: I have tried with it also..I have tried different alternatives.But didn't work

Comment: According to the changes I have done, the error is changing

Comment: Also used javascript script executor also @Tuks

Comment: This is the error message:"Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string"..And this is the stacktrace "[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6cb05c"...I have added a logger to know whether it is identifying the element.It was identified..But do not sending keys

Comment: is that code working fine other than Firefox ?

Comment: No.It is not working in chrome driver also..I think the error is with sendKeys,click keywords.Because there is no error when I comment that line and run the code.I just tried to find element and send keys.Elemetn is found.But keys are not passed.But,this code was executed successfully previously

Comment: I guess the issue is, we are not sending the sendkeys to the correct input tag. Can you try these.. WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='serchkey']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='serchkey']")).sendKeys("toy"); //Adding input tag in the xpath and sending the string directly.

Comment: It is known issue with Gecko version https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/647

Comment: @santhoshkumar.I tried that code segment.But no solution for me..Is there any alternative ways?

Comment: @kushal.,if it is a known error..then how we proceed forward with this?

Comment: I've found that we cannot use xpath which refer more than one element of the website.The site I using to automate, has same id for same element repeatedly. There is a searchbar which I tried to test.It has same id,xpath for mobile div,desktop div and etc.I think that was the failure to find the element. I have removed the wait until visibility of element phrase.Then I could to send keys for log in page in same web site.When I am using wait it didn't work.Thank you the great help have you done for me.Even though they worked for me or not as a beginner I have learnt from them something.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work:

```
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.id("serchkey"));

javascriptSendKeys(element,"toy");

private void javascriptSendKeys(WebElement yourElement, String yourText){ 
     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;
     executor.executorScript("arguments[0].value='" + yourText + "';", yourElement);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work dear..My machine was stuck.then I downloaded eclipse 64bit Neon version, selenium 3.4 and gecko driver 0.16.1

Comment: I've found that we cannot use xpath which refer more than one element of the website.The site I using to automate, has same id for same element repeatedly. There is a searchbar which I tried to test.It has same id,xpath for mobile div,desktop div and etc.I think that was the failure to find the element. I have removed the wait until visibility of element phrase.Then I could to send keys for log in page in same web site.When I am using wait it didn't work.Thank you the great help have you done for me.Even though they worked for me or not as a beginner I have learnt from them something.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Great job done by specifying the Test Environment details as:

- Selenium Webdriver 3.3.1
- GeckoDriver 16.0

Now, if you have a look at the documentation of geckodriver v0.16.0 [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), you will find a Heading as: **"Note that geckodriver v0.16.0 is only compatible with Selenium 3.4 and greater."**

So the solution to your Question is to upgrade your Selenium to 3.4.0 from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I have tried with selenium 3.4..but id doesn't solve.Now it doesn't open the URL..That error is too long to send you.

Comment: My machine was stuck.then I downloaded eclipse 64bit Neon version, selenium 3.4 and gecko driver 0.16.1

Comment: But it is also failed to execute program.Is there any version compatible errors?Firefox is53 (32bit)

Comment: I've found that we cannot use xpath which refer more than one element of the website.The site I using to automate, has same id for same element repeatedly. There is a searchbar which I tried to test.It has same id,xpath for mobile div,desktop div and etc.I think that was the failure to find the element. I have removed the wait until visibility of element phrase.Then I could to send keys for log in page in same web site.When I am using wait it didn't work.Thank you the great help have you done for me.Even though they worked for me or not as a beginner I have learnt from them something.Thank you